# Sense CTRL+X while raw_input>

Tags: python, bash

I have a script that looks like (I have imported all required modules.):

```
def _find_getch():
try:
    import termios
except ImportError:
    # Non-POSIX. Return msvcrt's (Windows') getch.
    import msvcrt
    return msvcrt.getch

# POSIX system. Create and return a getch that manipulates the tty.
import sys, tty
def _getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

return _getch

getch = _find_getch()
#keypress for CTRL+X is 88

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    controlPressed = False
    file = ''
    while not controlPressed:
        latest = raw_input("> ")
        key = getch
        if key == '<function _getch at 0x7f9602558e60>':
            controlPressed = True
            sys.exit()
```

I run this script in the terminal and it never senses when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. How would I sense <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> while `raw_input` is running?

Comment: The indentation seems wrong. Please fix so that your code passes simple syntax checking. Perhaps copy-paste the entire script again, select the pasted block, and press ctrl-K to indent it as code (this is a feature of the Stack Overflow desktop version; if you are on a mobile device, maybe temporarily switch to the "full site" view from the link in the footer on this page).

Comment: @tripleee When I posted the code, I was not on mobile, I was on my laptop. The ctrl-K seems very useful p, I will try it out! I'm not sure about indenting for everything before the second comment, all that code I found in a Gist or on SO. Everything aft that is good. Is there any other module I can use to get key presses?

Comment: The indentation is still wrong; for an obvious example, the `try` after the `def` cannot not be indented. We can tell that it's wrong, but trying to guess how it's supposed to be is near impossible once you have more than a couple of indentation levels. Again: please fix your code; there is no way we can help you when the parts your question *isn't* about are not working correctly.

Comment: If you aren't particular that it is CTRL+X, you could use CTRL+C and add `try` and `except Exception` (for Windows) and `except KeyboardInterrupt` for Mac (and Linux, though not tested).

Comment: what is up with the return _getch below the _getch function definition?  It isn't in a function so it can't return anything, and if it was it would return the function object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The _getch function didn't work properly.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I never found a solution. :/